# How to properly copy html/css snippet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to copy this html/css snippet: 
https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/8k3

I copy all the html.
I copy all the css including the linked style sheets into one document.

When i run the copied code in the browser, it renders properly however none of the elements respond to clicks etc..

For this example when i click the "Dropdown" button, in my copied code, nothing happens.

how can i properly copy this snippet so it works?

As ive said i tried copying ALL the css available into one document, still not working.

Comment: This is not enough to go on.  You need to open your developers tools in your browser, go to the console, and report any errors you might see there.

Comment: The reason i posted this was to get some experienced advice on how to properly copy html elements from a page with css styling.  Apparently its not as simple as just copying the html and css files as this often leads to corrupt html rendering for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to copy/paste these lines into the `<head></head>` section of your HTML document:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

*Found (via DevTools) in the `<head></head>` section of the page you referenced.*